# Flutter Future Provider and Sqflite (the right usage)

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, sqflite

As a beginner I need an architectural advice for following scenario.

My application writes a tiny amount of data and return a tiny query result to the user interface (from sqflite) for each user interaction (click).

There can be at least three ways to do so;

1. Future Provider (Most appropriate way as I see)
2. ChangeNotifierProvider & Future Builder
3. Using Flutter List and do all db operations in the background with using future-then functions.

I couldn't succeed on Future Provider and couldn't find a similar example. (almost all future provider examples are related with web services not sqflite)

Because of this I started asking which way is right or can be another way? Future Provider can be the most appropriate way if you say, I will focus on this.

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return query based on the user input, you need to go with the second option, i have personally developed a production level app using this strategy and it works like charm.

Here's the link to my github repository for that app, if you feel any difficulty in implementation you may ask.

Code that contains `ChangeNotifierProvider' for DateTime
https://github.com/asadamatic/Daily-Todo/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Code that contains `Consumer` for ChangeNotifierProvider for DateTime
https://github.com/asadamatic/Daily-Todo/blob/master/lib/Screens/HomeScreen.dart

You nay want to check out the app and see if you can relate to it,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.legacyllc.dailytodo

Comment: Couln't access the github for code. I'll download the application to see how it works.My app is not a todo application but maybe similar in database transactions perpective.

Comment: Okay my mistake, that's a private repository. I have changed it's visibility to public, you can access it now.

Comment: My pleasure  I would want to know about your project when it's done :)